# Unit testing nestjs guards Unknown authentication strategy

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, passport.js, nestjs

Trying to write unit tests as described [here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs/blob/master/apps/complex-sample/src/cat/cat.guard.spec.ts) but no idea how to get around this error

```
Exception has occurred: Error: Unknown authentication strategy "test-jwt"
  at attempt (/home/user/Workspace/project/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:190:39)
    at authenticate
```

auth file

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport";

@Injectable()
export class MyGuard extends AuthGuard('test-jwt') { }
```

test

```
import { ExecutionContext } from "@nestjs/common";
import { MyGuard } from "./mygaurd";

it('test' () => {
    const context: ExecutionContext = {
      switchToHttp: () => context,
      getRequest: () => {
        return {
          headers: {
            authorization: `bearer ${jwt}` 
          }
        }
      },
      getResponse: () => { }
    } as unknown as ExecutionContext

    const guard = new MyGuard()

    expect(guard.canActivate(context)).toBeTrue();
})
```

The actual implementation works fine, I add it to a controller.

```
@UseGuards(MyGuard)
export class MyController {
```

I don't even need to add it as a provider or anything in my setup so not sure what other code to include.

I implemented a custom strategy which may be related

```
import { Strategy, ExtractJwt } from "passport-jwt";
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";

@Injectable()
export class MyStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'test-jwt') {
   
  constructor() {
    super({ 
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(), 
      secretOrKey: 'secret'
    })
  }

  async validate(payload) {
    ...
  }
}
```

And of course `MyStrategy` is added as a provider in my app.

I have unit tests covering my custom strategy already so it is really just the guard left

**EDIT:**

Trying Jay's suggestion below gets me a little closer but i'm still struggling.

It seems `passport.use()` expects a name and Strategy rather than a function (so TS compilation fails) so I tried

```
import passport, { Strategy } from "passport";
...

passport.use('test-jwt', {
   authenticate: (payload) => true
} as Strategy);
```

and the error disappears, but the test now outputs

```
expect(received).toBeTrue()

Expected value to be true:
  true
Received:
  {}
```

Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those quirky things with passport that I never thought I'd see. So, passport uses strategy names to determine what authentication method is actually being used, right? All of these strategies get registered to the passport context using `passport.use(name, method)` in the general scheme of things. In the context of Nest, this happens when you create a custom strategy, extend `PassportStrategy` and add the strategy as a provider [as seen here](https://github.com/nestjs/passport/blob/master/lib/passport/passport.strategy.ts#L40). Later, the method `passport.authenticate(strategy, (err, req, res, next)` is called [during the `AuthGuard#canActivate`](https://github.com/nestjs/passport/blob/master/lib/auth.guard.ts#L98) method (the codes a bit complex, but this is where it happens). Because passport has never seen `passport.use('test-jwt', authMethod)` in the context of your test, it ends up not knowing what to do other than throwing the error about "Unknown authentication strategy".

Normally, the `validate` method is what becomes the `authMethod`, but if you're just needing this for the context of your test you can do something like

```js
it('test' () => {
    passport.use('test-jwt', (payload) => true);
    const context: ExecutionContext = {
      switchToHttp: () => context,
      getRequest: () => {
        return {
          headers: {
            authorization: `bearer ${jwt}` 
          }
        }
      },
      getResponse: () => { }
    } as unknown as ExecutionContext

    const guard = new MyGuard()

    expect(guard.canActivate(context)).toBeTrue();
})
```

and it should work out all right. You an then modify the value returned from that method, or make it a `jest.fn()` so that you can check what it was called with and modify what it returns if you need to do extra testing on the guard.

Comment: I updated my question with my new issue. `canActivate` should return a `boolean` so the fact I get an empty object returned makes me think i've still not implemented this test correctly.

Comment: You probably need to await the `guard.canActivate` and make the test async. I believe Nest treats the `AuthGuard#canActivate` as async by default

Comment: I tried making the test async, but my mock is causing issues. At line `87` in `auth.guards.js` the Promise never resolves and my test times out. On a live call `handleRequest` in my custom guard is called immediately after that line. I've spent some hours stepping through the code but callbacks are not my strong point. I believe my test is failing either at `createPassportContext` or when executing `yield passportFn(...)`

Comment: How do I get hold of the `passport` variable?